# What verbs in English never take nouns as complements, and is there a term for this?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, verbs, syntactic-analysis

I can think of only a few verbs like *exist* and *belong* that never take ordinary nouns as object complements. (see below)

We never say things like, *She exists a doctor.
Rather, we would say, She exists as a doctor (S+V+pp)

However, we might see an infinitive functioning as an object complement as in, "She exists to heal others". She exists to do something - *to heal* functions as an object complement. But the infinitive is also quite verbal and could be understood as a clause - *she exists, so she can heal others*. This is not really about existence per se, but rather the purpose of her existence, and hence this complement phrase really produces a different meaning for the verb. We could simply say, *She exists* because exist does not require a complement to have complete meaning.

*Belong* is a little different because it is incomplete, particularly in a bare sentence. Without sufficient context, say, in answer to the question, 'do you belong?' we would rarely if ever just say, 'I belong.' Nor would we say, 'it belongs.' We normally complement this verb with a prepositional phrase or adverb phrase. *I belong here, it belongs there, she belongs to the club, it belongs to him, and so on.* And we never say things like, *the wallet belongs me*, or *I belong club.*

So, back to the original thought, are there any other verbs in English that never take an ordinary noun as a complement, and is there a term for such words?

Here are a few other candidates:

- look
- sit
- fall
- live
- venture
- happen
- occur
- smile

Comment: I think the word you're  looking for is *intransitive* verbs. And there are many more than two.

Comment: How about "laugh", "smile", "occur" and dozens more?

Comment: @Robusto: Yes, but the term 'intransitive' only identifies how a verb is functioning in a sentence, it does not identify an inherent property of the verb-word itself.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, these are candidates - though laugh and smile are quite limited to laugh a laugh or smile a smile, not sure what noun phrase would follow occur, can you give an example?

Comment: @Ubu: Well, *verb* only identifies how it functions in a sentence, for that matter. So now I have no idea what "property" you're talking about.

Comment: @UbuEnglish I was tempted to say "an occurrence". But then that would be the subject wouldn't it? "An occurrence occurred..." "Occur" is like "happen". I see no possibility of a direct object.

Comment: @Robusto : lets say that it is a property of most verbs is that they can take both object (OC) and adverbial complements (AC), to complete, determine or otherwise complement the verb's meaning. But not all words used as verbs can do this - some only take AC while others only take OC.  I think that when grammarians say a verb is intransitive,  they mean that the verb is complemented adverbially or has no complement at all, in a particular instance of use, not that it isn't used transitively also.

Comment: @Robusto : So, yes, a verb is a word function, not a property of  words used as verbs. But transitivity is a property of verbs in the sense that they all verbs have this property, some can be used both ways (often with different meanings produced) while others are only used one way. That's what I meant by property.

Comment: *We never say things like, “She exists a doctor.” Rather, we would say, “She exists as a doctor.”* Well, I've never heard anyone say the latter either. Have you heard anyone say *She works and lives a doctor*? In answer to the question "Do you belong?" You could simply reply "Yes" or "No". I see nothing inherently wrong with the statement "I belong", said by a person who embraces the universe and the feeling of oneness with nature, it can stand alone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA : I think you're missing the point. This isn't about deriving meaning from context. It's not about common usage. But to your point - 'She exists as a doctor' is at least sensible, if not common, where 'she exists a doctor' is not.

Comment: But you claimed "…Rather, we would say “She exists as a doctor.”…" and I am disputing that. No, we wouldn't say that. I don't understand why "collect" is in the list. We can say "She collects books"

Comment: @Mari-LouA : Fine, I completely agree with you.  It's awkward but probably acceptable. But what's the point of disputing this - is it relevant to the topic? ANd you're right about 'correct' - I've removed it. 'Venture' is also suspect.

Comment: @WS2 : "I was tempted to say 'an occurrence'. But then that would be the subject wouldn't it?" I like this observation, because it reflects the agency requirements of the verb - 'one' can't occur something. The verb seems to require an inanimate subject.

Comment: @UbuEnglish You could try "There occurred an occurrence". But I don't think even that turns "occurrence" into a complement/object.

Comment: It occurred there was no there there.